# Web service issue

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
 <script src="BindData.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
<Services>
<asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService.asmx"  />
</Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

BindData.js

```
GetContent();
function GetContent() {
    WebService.GetData(OnSuccess,OnFailure);
}

function OnSuccess(result) {
    var grid = document.getElementById("GridView1");
    grid = result;
}

function OnFailure() {
    alert("Error");  
}
```

WebService.cs

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public WebService () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public  IEnumerable<ContentPageNav> GetData() {
        DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
        var query = (from n in dc.ContentPageNavs
                    select n).ToList();
        return query;

    }

}
```

WebService is not getting called. Its not even stopping at a breakpoint in javascript.

Comment: You think that might be because you are calling the function **before** it's declared? You are in a scripting language, it works from top to bottom.

Comment: @sly_Chandan, I've rolled your edit back as you'd removed most of the content and the actual *question*, if there was something specifically you were trying to alter to enhance the question (I couldn't pick out what that was), I'd suggest trying again, but without removing so much as to make your question unanswerable! =)

Comment: Please dont rollback my question as I have moved ahead with my issue.

Comment: @sly_Chandan, fair enough but what's above is now *not a question*. It's a block of code with no supporting question. As such I've voted to close as (1) It's not a question and (2) It will be of little or no use to *anyone* else who finds this via google in the future.

Comment: @sly so in such case please edit the question with what you did, leaving it standing in the air is not really helping anyone.

Comment: @Shadow, "standing in the air" - I've never heard that one before, but very apt! =)

Comment: I guess that's because it's translation of Hebrew phrase.. glad the intention is clear though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not web service, it's Web **Method**.. anyway your mistake is trying to assign the element itself instead of its inner HTML. Fix is as simple as changing the line to:

```
grid.innerHTML = result;
```

You might better use UpdatePanel though, sounds more fit for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript isn't compiled so when your script encounters the line `GetContent();` it will look for a method called `GetContent` on your window object but there isn't one. Then it reads the next line and starts creating a method called `GetContent` on your window object and so on down the script.

The basic upshot of this is that you can't use a function until it's been declared! Move your `GetContent();` call to after the definition of the `GetContent` method in your script and it'll work. Best to move it to the last line so that Success and Failure have a chance to be declared also.

Comment: I have called the GetContent() function at the end and it still doesnt stop at breakpoint.

Comment: Have you tried just putting an alert in method ahead of your Ajax call? Have you tried breakpointing inside your WebMethod? You do realise that the GridView doesn't work the way you are trying to use it?

Comment: OK. Here is the situation now...I have put an alert and that actually displays the alert message. Now the only concern is how do I bind gridview to the results returned.

Comment: Hey....I guess I cant bind the data of gridview on client side.. Am I right?